# Releasing an NSDictionary (or other NSObjects) that are a return value.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Let us say that I have a method like this:

```
- (NSDictionary*)getBigDictionaryOfSecrets
{

NSDictionary *theDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
theDic = // insert contents of dictionary

return theDic;
}
```

How and where should one properly release this?

Comment: Note that the `theDic = // insert...` would be a leak. You've already allocated a dictionary and assigned it to theDic. If you want to put values in the dictionary, you should do that at initialization (see `-initWithObjectsAndKeys:` or any of the other NSDictionary initializers) or else create a mutable dictionary instead and add values after creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `return [theDic autorelease]`. This will not release the dictionary immediately, allowing the caller to `retain` it.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what `autorelease` is for. Do something like this:

```
- (NSDictionary*)bigDictionaryOfSecrets 
{ 
    NSDictionary *theDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"bar", @"foo", nil];

    return [theDic autorelease];
}
```

Read more about `autorelease` in the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW6).

Comment: As a side note, the prefix "get" is typically used for methods that return objects and values indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

You either autorelease it or you document ***very well*** that the caller is responsible for releasing it.

Comment: Don't return objects that the caller is supposed to release, it goes against every other method in Objective-C. Being consistent in programming is how we deal with the complexity of programs. Also people don't usually read the documentation unless they can not tell what the method is supposed to do from it's name.

Comment: I know people don't read documentation.  But they do that at their peril in any event.  In this case "very well" would mean documenting in the h file, at the head of the method in the m file, and at all places where it's used.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the return object on autorelease should work. Remember that the receiver must retain the returned object.

```
- (NSDictionary*)getBigDictionaryOfSecrets 
{ 
  NSDictionary *theDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
  theDic = // insert contents of dictionary

  return [theDic autorelease];
}
```

Comment: @Caleb out of curiosity, why did you improve the example code on this answer instead of yours?

Comment: @albertamg: Mistake. I rolled back my edit and moved it to my own answer once I realized what I'd done.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the answers provided, instead of using `autorelease` you could do something like this:

```
- (void)populateBigDictionaryOfSecrets(const NSMutableDictionary*)aDictionary
{
    // insert contents of dictionary
}
```

And create/release the dictionary in the class/method where it will be used.

Comment: It should be noted that this is not typical in Cocoa or Cocoa Touch development.